# Pyspark dataframe into hive table

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

How can I parse a pyspark df in a hive table?
Also, is there any way to create a csv with header from my df?

I do not use pandas, my dfs are created with spark.sql() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read **`hive table`** data in pyspark with df then write the df with **`header`** using **`.option("header","true")`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.sql("select * from <db>.<hive_table>")

df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").csv("<file_path>")
```

**`UPDATE:`**

```
#choosee mode either overwrite/append
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("<hive_db>.<hive_table>")

#or using spark sql
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql("insert into <hive_db>.<hive_table> select * from tmp")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. df.write.mode worked perfect.
For the hive, I want to put a df into a table, not a table into a df

Comment: Please check `UPDATE` section of the answer!